# Does RequiredAttribute somehow implement IClientValidation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

[Prelude]
I was coding a custom **ValidationAttribute** when i wondered where should i put it in my framework. First i thought that since i was going to use **IClientValidation**, it should be somewhere inside a new project that has the MVC assembly as dependency but then i remembered that **RequiredAttribute** is inside **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll** which doesn't have any MVC dependency.

[Question]
How does **RequiredAttribute** work with client-side validation? I opened it's source and not only doesn't it implement **IClientValidation**, but also it's not a partial class that could be *"extended"*.

Comment: You can always use an adapter - like DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(); I guess RequiredAttribute is in the default set of adapters.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar Oh, look at that... **RequiredAttributeAdapter**... Adapters! I didn't know them, thanks! I can imagine all of the default ones get registered when the application starts.